# Porting OpenGL code from C++ to Python

Tags: c++, python, opengl, wxpython, pyopengl

I have written a game in C++ / OpenGL and am supposed to port the same to Python.

After some research online, I found out PyOpenGL 3.0.2 and WxPython 2.8.12.1 bindings for 2.7 version of Python work good for Python / OpenGL programming.

Can you suggest me if this a right combination to start porting my C++ game to ?

If there are any other easy ways to get this porting done, help me with those.

Comment: I think you will have more problems with wxWidgets/wxPython than with PyOpenGL. I wonder, though, why would you want to port that game - C++ is multiplatform, so what's the reason?

Comment: I have to port the C++/Opengl code to Python and Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at what's built in to wxPython? See http://wiki.wxpython.org/GLCanvas

There's also this recipe that seems to combine openGL Python wrappers and wx: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/325392-use-wxpythonopengl-to-draw-a-sphere/